# Angular 9 how to read an uploaded json file into an object in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, filereader

I am trying to upload a json file into a variable and read its content as object:

```
  this.file = event.target.files[0];
    let fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsText(this.file)
    fileReader.onload = () => {
      let array = fileReader.result;
      console.log(array)
    }
    fileReader.onerror = (error) => {
      console.log(error);
  }
```

Here is the html:

```
<button type="button" mat-raised-button (click)="fileInput.click()">Upload File</button>
<input hidden (change)="onChangeFile($event)" #fileInput type="file" id="file">
```

The consoled value is text and not an object.

Comment: Did you try to use `JSON.parse` to parse the string into an object?

Comment: Yep and it didn't work. @OctavianMărculescu